# C# Change DataTable Column DataType

Tags: c#, datatable

I have DataTable with several columns. The number of columns is dynamic, but they are all string.
I need to convert the DataTable's columns from string to the DataType which would be the best match for all the rows in that column.

**Example:**

> If all the rows in a column are numbers, then change the datatype of that column to number; or to DateTime if the values are dates; otherwise leave as string.

How can this be done? I understand that I must create a new DataTable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an outline of how I would do it.  Basically use TryParse methods of the primitive types to determine the highest count.  Then add a new column with the new type, converting as many values as possible.  Ones that can't be converted will be left as DBNull.Value.

```
public class TypeCount {
    public int IntCount;
    public int LongCount;
    public int DoubleCount;
    public int DecimalCount;
    public int DateCount;
    // etc;

    // provide your own logic to determine the best type
    public Type BestType {
        get {
            int[] counts = new int[] { IntCount, LongCount, DoubleCount, DecimalCount, DateCount };
            Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(long), typeof(double), typeof(decimal), typeof(DateTime) };
            Type bt = typeof(String);
            int max = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < counts.Length; i++) {
                if (counts[i] > max) {
                    bt = types[i];
                    max = counts[i];
                }
            }
            return bt;
        }
    }
}

public static void TryParse(String s, NumberStyles ns, DateTimeStyles dts, IFormatProvider fp, String[] dateFormats, TypeCount counts) {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return;

    long l;
    int i;
    double d;
    decimal m;

    // could test byte and short too if needed
    if (int.TryParse(s, ns, fp, out i)) {
        counts.IntCount++;
        counts.LongCount++; // if int parses, then long also parses
    }
    else if (long.TryParse(s, ns, fp, out l))
        counts.LongCount++;

    // etc.

    foreach (String f in dateFormats) {
        DateTime date;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(s, f, fp, dts, out date))
            counts.DateCount++;
    }
}

public static void ConvertColumns(DataTable table) {
    IFormatProvider fp = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    NumberStyles ns = NumberStyles.Any;
    DateTimeStyles dts = DateTimeStyles.None;
    String[] dateFormats = new String[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "MM/dd/yyyy" };

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++) {
        DataColumn col = table.Columns[i];
        if (col.DataType != typeof(String))
            continue;

        TypeCount counts = new TypeCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++) {
            String s = table.Rows[j][col] as String;
            TryParse(s, ns, dts, fp, dateFormats, counts);
        }

        Type bestType = counts.BestType;
        DataColumn temp = null;
        if (bestType == typeof(int)) {
            temp = table.Columns.Add("temp", typeof(int));
            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++) {
                int val = 0;
                String s = table.Rows[j][col] as String;
                if (int.TryParse(s, ns, fp, out val))
                    table.Rows[j][temp] = val;
            }
        }
        //else if (bestType == ...) {}

        if (temp != null) {
            temp.SetOrdinal(col.Ordinal);
            table.Columns.Remove(col);
            temp.ColumnName = col.ColumnName;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty risky operation that you are trying to perform. All you would need is a single unpredicted value and you will have an exception plus testing each cell for value would be pretty costly.  Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish I'd suggest
1. Test all cells in each column to get an idea what type you would need (very costly)
2. Create new DataTable with correct DataType in each column then copy content from old one. Compared to testing this would be lightning fas